# What are the criterias for calling a function a task?

Tags: embedded, task

How  do we Exactly define tasks in embedded programming. 
I mean what are the criterias which has to be fulfilled, to call a function a task.

Comment: The 'C' language does not define the word **task**; it is OS dependent.  It may have a precise meaning in languages like [ADA](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/task/info).

Answer (score 1):

A task is a more general term than "process" as in Linux or "thread" as in Java. Those terms have very specific meanings in those contexts. The term "task" is meant to be less well-defined.

A task is a piece of code run by an operating system that is given control of the processor for a time determined by the OS. From the point of view of the task, it is the only code running on the processor, and interacts with other tasks through the operating system.

To manage the running of tasks, the OS must keep track of code and context for the task. That is, when the task is interrupted, the OS must be able to restore the processor not only to the point on the code where the task was running, but also the state of the processor itself.

A task in an OS may be required to be specified in the form of a C function, this is not necessary. For example, in Linux, processes can be shell scripts or executable programs. In Java, threads are the run() method of a class.

In a system where tasks are specified by functions, the function alone does not describe the task. For example, several tasks could be running the code of the same function. Instead, the defining feature of task versus function is that some form of OS or scheduler must exist and is used to create and control tasks, whether the code of the task is given by a function or not.